# ¿Por qué - y desde cuándo - se utiliza "alma mater" para designar la universidad?

Tags: etimología, historia, locuciones, latinismo, lenguaje-académico

El [Diccionario de la lengua española](https://dle.rae.es/) de la Real Academia Española define

[*alma mater*](https://dle.rae.es/alma%20mater):

> Loc. lat.; literalmente 'madre nutricia'.
>
> 1. f. U. para designar la universidad.

pero su uso en español parece ser relativamente moderno (no he encontrado referencias en español anteriores al siglo XX) y no resulta evidente la conexión entre el significado de la locución y su uso en español. ¿Cómo se estableció ese significado y cuándo?

Veo que tiene su propia entrada en el [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/alma%20m%C3%A1ter), por lo que no puedo resistirme a incluirla, especialmente porque aclara por qué su genero es *femenino* (**la** *alma mater*) y no maculino, y sobre el uso incorrecto con otros significados:

> 1. Loc. lat. que significa literalmente ‘madre nutricia’. Se emplea, como locución nominal femenina, para referirse metafóricamente a una universidad, aludiendo a su función proveedora de alimento intelectual: «Constituí una “Asociación de Amigos de la Universidad de Madrid”, cuyo fin principal era la ayuda moral y material a nuestra alma máter» (Laín Descargo [Esp. 1976]). Desde el punto de vista etimológico, lo más correcto, y también lo más recomendable en el uso culto, es decir la alma máter, y no el alma máter, ya que la palabra alma es en latín un adjetivo, no un sustantivo, y el artículo la únicamente se transforma en el ante sustantivos femeninos que comienzan por /a/ tónica (→ el, 2.1).
>
> 2. Es impropio, aunque frecuente hoy, el uso de esta locución con el sentido de ‘persona que da vida o impulso a algo’: «Es el gerente y alma máter del mayor proyecto empresarial organizado nunca por un sindicato español» (Cambio 16 [Esp.] 5.11.90). Este uso impropio se debe a la confusión entre el adjetivo latino alma (fem. de almus ‘que nutre o alimenta’) y el sustantivo español alma (del lat. anima). Al considerar erróneamente la palabra alma como un sustantivo, se antepone en estos casos la forma el del artículo.

Answer (score 3):

Efectivamente, el uso de *alma mater* parece ser relativamente reciente. En el CORDE aparecen algunos casos antiguos pero corresponden a textos escritos en latín. De los escritos en español, el más antiguo es este:

> *La fundación de hospitales, el establecimiento de una universidad con anhelos de ser el alma mater de la sociedad criolla, y que daba a la Nueva España el rango de potencia intelectual [...].*
>
> Justo Sierra, "Evolución política del pueblo mexicano", 1900 - 1902 (México).

Sin embargo, en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España se encuentran casos más antiguos, y además más esclarecedores:

> Cuando se matricula un cursante se pone su nombre en el registro de la universidad, se le admite como uno de sus miembros, y se le reconoce como á hijo de la *Alma mater Edimensis*; no se le exige juramento, ni profesion de fe, ni que se someta á reconocer artículos de religion de ninguna clase; se admiten libremente personas de todas religiones ya sean católicas, ya protestantes, ya de otra religion cualquiera, y no se les hace una sola pregunta relativa á ello.
>
> **El Corresponsal (Madrid).** 7/11/1841, [página 4](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0029052890&page=4&search=%22alma%20mater%22&lang=es).

El artículo habla sobre la Universidad de Edimburgo. En el idioma inglés, el uso de *Alma mater* se atestigua, [según la web de Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Alma%20Mater#etymonline_v_10897), desde 1710. Luego es probable que el uso de *Alma mater* como "la entidad que te ha enseñado a ser lo que eres" provenga de este idioma. También hay otros artículos en la hemeroteca de mediados del siglo XIX que hablan sobre la dulce madre que es el estudio, aclarando que con "dulce madre" se refieren a "alma mater". E incluso hay otros casos donde se usa *Alma mater* fuera del contexto de la universidad:

> La libertad ama á las artes, es su rayo generador, el *alma mater* del genio y de la gloria.
>
> **Semanario pintoresco español.** 4/9/1853, n.º 36, [página 4](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003146050&page=4&search=%22alma%20mater%22&lang=es).

E incluso tienes este otro:

> Es también una promesa, como el arco-iris; es la sonrisa de la autoridad que vela por la seguridad pública; es el ojo y la mano de la patria, *alma mater*, que nunca abandona el solícito cuidado de sus hijos.
>
> **La Época (Madrid. 1849).** 25/2/1863, n.º 4.603, [página 1](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000178696&page=1&search=%22alma%20mater%22&lang=es).

Así pues, se encuentran casos de *alma mater* desde mediados del siglo XIX en la hemeroteca, con un significado amplio de "aquella entidad que te enseña a manejarte en la vida y cuida de ti, después de tu propia madre". Dado que en el Reino Unido se venía usando el término desde mucho antes, mi suposición viendo los primeros artículos donde aparece el término es que posiblemente provenga de allí.